# Maven repository has an invald java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: java, rest, maven, api, spring-boot

I would like to build an API web application related REST service.
Before deploying the API application, I got an issue:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to read Class-Path attribute from manifest of jar file:/C:/Users/Lukas/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/5.0.12.Final/hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls.getUrlsFromClassPathOfJarManifestIfPossible(ChangeableUrls.java:110)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls.fromUrlClassLoader(ChangeableUrls.java:96)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.DefaultRestartInitializer.getUrls(DefaultRestartInitializer.java:93)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.DefaultRestartInitializer.getInitialUrls(DefaultRestartInitializer.java:56)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter.<init>(Restarter.java:140)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter.initialize(Restarter.java:546)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartApplicationListener.onApplicationStartingEvent(RestartApplicationListener.java:67)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(RestartApplicationListener.java:45)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:167)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.starting(EventPublishingRunListener.java:69)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.starting(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:292)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
    at com.autoparts.autoeshop.Application.main(Application.java:12)
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(ZipFile.java:60)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:734)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(ZipFile.java:434)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
    at sun.misc.IOUtils.readFully(IOUtils.java:65)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getBytes(JarFile.java:425)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifestFromReference(JarFile.java:193)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifest(JarFile.java:180)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls.getUrlsFromManifestClassPathAttribute(ChangeableUrls.java:131)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls.getUrlsFromClassPathOfJarManifestIfPossible(ChangeableUrls.java:107)
    ... 16 more
```

How can I find a way to deal with the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Its a common error indicating corrupted artifact. Remove it manually from maven local repository and try to build again.

To do this delete everything in

```
C:/Users/Lukas/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager
```

and `mvn compile` in project directory.

Comment: Doesn't work it. Same an issue about class-path.
Windows cmd doesn't recognize "mvn compile".
I think this I should remove all .m2 files then maybe everything ok. I will try doing this.

Comment: If you run from eclipse you must run maven from eclipse as well. as for "unrecognized" mvn - configure your PATH and it will be recognized "magically"

Answer (score 0):

**If you use eclipse, try this.**

**Check your maven repository.**

Windows + R => Copy and Paste => C:/Users/Lukas/.m2/repository

> 1) if it does exist. (C:/Users/Lukas/.m2/repository)

2) Eclipse > Package Explorer(or Project Explorer) > R-Click >

***"Maven Clean" after "Maven Install"***

[image]

Eclipse > Package Explorer(or Project Explorer) > R-Click >

**"Maven > Update Project..."**

[image]

> 3) if does not exist. (C:/Users/Lukas/.m2/repository)

4) find your real path of maven repository then, update repository path in your eclipse 
preferences.

***copy and paste your repository path to "Local Repository" after click "Reindex" button.***

[image]

> **5) if it still has error, add following codes to pom.xml file.**
>     then, execute 2).

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.12.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

> 6) Run your project

Comment: it is working. Firstly, thank you for everything.
But last an issue: "Error: Could not find or load main class com.autoparts.autoeshop.Application"
I have tried uesd cmd line: 
C:\Users\Lukas\AutoEShop\autoeshop\src\main\java\com\autoparts\autoeshop>set class-"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin";

System says: Environment variable class-"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin"; not defined